# WCSession: Data submitted on iOS is never received on the Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-2, watchconnectivity, wcsession

I am working on a small time tracking app for iOS. The user can create any number of activity and then track how much time he spend on each of them (e.g. sleeping, driving to work, eating, working, etc.)

Now I would like to add Apple Watch support: The user should be able to pick an activity from a list on his watch, enter a time value and submit this result to the iOS app which then updates its data.

So, I need communication in both directions:

```
iOS -> Watch:
    List of configured activties

Watch -> iOS
    Add time XY for activity 123
```

I implemented the `WCSession` on both sides but no matter what I try, there seems to be no communication:

```
// iOS App Delegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  
    ...
    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }
}

- (void)updateActitviesOnWatch:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)data {
    if (session != nil && session.paired && session.activationState == WCSessionActivationStateActivated) {
        [session updateApplicationContext:data error:nil];

        [session sendMessage:data replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage) {
            NSLog(@"sendMessage : success");
        } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            NSLog(@"sendMessage : error");
        }];

        [session transferUserInfo:data];
    }
}


// WatchExtension ExtensionDelegate.m
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching {
    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }
}

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session activationDidCompleteWithState:(WCSessionActivationState)activationState error:(nullable NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"WK activationDidCompleteWithState");
}

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)userInfo {    
    NSLog(@"WK session didReceiveUserInfo");
}

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)applicationContext {
    NSLog(@"WK session didReceiveApplicationContext");
}

- (void)session:(WCSession * __nonnull)session didFinishUserInfoTransfer:(WCSessionUserInfoTransfer *)userInfoTransfer error:(nullable NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"WK session didFinishUserInfoTransfer");
}
```

No matter which method is used to send the data on iOS (`updateApplicationContext:error:`, `sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler` or `transferUserInfo:`) non of the receiving delegate methods is called on the Watch.

**What ma I doing wrong?**

What is the correct method to transferee the data in the first place?

Comment: Are you sure the session is active *and* reachable?

Comment: I mean this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615683-reachable?language=objc

Comment: Yes, when adding `...&& session.reachable` to the `if`clause in in `updateActivitiesOnWatch` the data is send but not not received

Comment: Do you get any error or info message in the logs? // What is the object you send in "data", is it NSCoding compatible?